# Iterate Object list and map 2 or 3 items per row based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to achieve what's in the image below.

I will be receiving a prop which is a list of objects.

Plan to iterate over those and create the structure in following image.

There should be no more than 3 items per row.
All items that fall under the same title would be in the same block
which is either dark grey or white. If there is a 4th item under same title, it should move down
below but stay in same block. I do not want any borders. Added those in imaged just to illustrate.

BUT, when it comes to mobile size, I want it to be 2 items per row.

This is the structure of the prop being passed in.

```
const exampleProp = [
    "title1": [
        {
            name: "",
        },
        {
            name: "",
        },
        {
            name: "",
        },
    ],
    "title2": [
        {
            name: "",
        },
        {
            name: "",
        }
    ]
]
```

I plan to iterate over these and build those squre components.

At present I have the following trying to get a grid.

but this doesn't allow anything more than 3 rows in a shaded region nor does this

handle it when it comes to mobile where I want it to be 2 per row.

Plan to use media query for mobile.

Plus seems to be capturing wrong data.

My question is:

1. How can I repeat grey/white/grey/white for the background color for the container section.
2. How can I get more than 3 items within same color block if the title has more than 3 items.
3. Is there a better way to map and produce the result compared to current attempt.
4. Cos am failing to extract the titles properly and data looks incorrect.

CSS

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Component

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="grid-container">
            {
              props.list.map(titleList => (
                titleList.map(titleData => (
                  <div className="grid-item">{titleData.name}</div>
                ))
              ))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomComponent;
```

[Image For reference on the intended layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTAfb.png)

[image]

Comment: 1. In your loop, use the `index` from `map`, then `if(index %2 == 0) {` this is a even block, give it a white background, else give a gray background; 2. Set `grid-auto-flow: row;` on the `.container`; 3. The '.grid-item` div should go between the two map calls; 4. Have no idea what 4 means, but #3 may fix.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks. For point 3, meaning I don't need the second mapping since nothing goes in there?

Comment: I'm assuming you'll want something other than a black "box" - otherwise what is their purpose?